# Powershell fails on Window2019STD when create self-signed certificate

Tags: powershell, certificate

Works on Windows 10:

```
$fqdn=[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).HostName
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Provider "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider" -FriendlyName "Paralax" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1, 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2") -Subject $fqdn -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(2) -SerialNumber "6666666666" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature", "DataEncipherment", "KeyEncipherment" -HashAlgorithm SHA256 -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

But fails on Windows 2019 with error:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Provider type not defined. 0x80090017
(-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)
At line:2 char:1
+ New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Provider "Microsoft Platform  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
```

Comment: Run `certutil.exe -csplist` to see if `Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider` is available on your system. If it's not, choose another one.

Comment: Exactly the same list of providers.

Comment: Does your Windows Server 2019 machine have a Trusted Platform Module (TPM) at all? Because `Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider` is intended for protecting private keys using a TPM.

Comment: util shows the same list of providers but failed at the end: CertUtil: -csplist command FAILED: 0x80090030 (-2146893776 NTE_DEVICE_NOT_READY)
CertUtil: The device that is required by this cryptographic provider is not ready for use.

Comment: Probably failed because this is virtual machine